# Access Select Distinct on one field in a Multiple Column Listbox

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Hope someone can help, I've been trying to sort this for ages.

Basically the following statement goes in the rowsource for a listbox. It works fine as is, but I want to hide all multiple rows where `Transactions.SaleID` matches.

I've tried `GROUP BY, FIRST() and DISTINCT`, but can't get it to work!

Thanks, Anthony.

```
strCriteria = "SELECT Contacts.ContactID, Contacts.ForeNames, Transactions.ItemName,
     TransactionMethod.Method, 
     Transactions.SaleID, 
     Transactions.TransDate 
FROM (Contacts 
     INNER JOIN Transactions ON Contacts.ContactID = Transactions.ContactID) 
     INNER JOIN TransactionMethod ON Transactions.MethodID = TransactionMethod.TransactionMethodID 
WHERE (((Transactions.TransDate)" & iDate & ") AND ((Transactions.Completed)=True));"
```

Comment: When you say multiple rows are you saying the rows are identical in every field? If not which of the multiple rows do you want to see? What would you base your selection on? Latest date? ContractID?

Comment: Hi Fred, the data is individual transactions (transactionID) where a Sale (SaleID) identifies the grouping of them to the customer and payment. The way I've set it up the listbox shows different data depending on the options selected. When sorted by SaleID I've put a dsum in the code (not shown above for simplicity) and want to only show 1 item from the Sale group, not all the SaleID items. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to split the problem into two queries. One that is saved with a name. The other you write in vba so that iDate can be used as a filter. The first query uses SELECT DISTINCT to generate a list of the rows you need with duplicates removed. The second which you write in vba refers to the first one in its FROM clause.

Comment: Thanks, I could use a query, but would prefer it to be in the code. I looked at using a sub query within the sql statement, but couldn't figure out the syntax.